# which float precision are numpy arrays by default?

Tags: numpy, floating-point, precision

I wonder which format floats are in numpy array by default.
(or do they even get converted when declaring a np.array? if so how about python lists?)
e.g. float16,float32 or float64?

Comment: `float64` is the default for most modern machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont specify the data type when you create the array then `numpy` will infer the type, from the [docs](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)

> ***dtypedata-type, optional*** - The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type
>   required to hold the objects in the sequence

Answer (score 8):

`float64`. You can check it like

```
>>> np.array([1, 2]).dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> np.array([1., 2]).dtype
dtype('float64')
```